# LINQ query to get all data about object which is collection of objects when each item of collection has own collection

Tags: c#, linq

Could anyone give me a hint on how to resolve the next task?

I have such a classes structure

```
public class Test
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Question> Questions { get; set; }
}

public class Question
{
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public ICollection<AnswerItem> AnswerItems { get; set; }
}

public class AnswerItem
{
    public string Defenition { get; set; }
    public bool IsCorrect { get; set; }
}
```

After fetching the `[Test]` entity from DB I've got  `IQueryable<Test>`. And further, I wonder how to get all Question entities (as a list) with all info where each Question item would have all info about AnswerItem collection.
I have tried the next query, but it returns only a collection of all answers:

```
var questList = test.SelectMany(t => t.Questions.SelectMany(q => q.AnswerItems)).ToList();
```

And I need something like this:

```
Questions = new List<Question>
{
    new Question
    {
        Name = "Question_1",
        AnswerItems = new List<AnswerItem>
        {
            new AnswerItem { Name = "answer_1", IsCorrect = false },
            new AnswerItem { Name = "answer_2", IsCorrect = false }
        }
    },
    new Question
    {
        Name = "Question_2",
        AnswerItems = new List<AnswerItem>
        {
            new AnswerItem { Name = "answer_1", IsCorrect = false },
            new AnswerItem { Name = "answer_2", IsCorrect = false }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your query should looks like the following one:

```cs
var query =
    from t in ctx.Tests
    from q in t.Questions
    select new
    {
        Name = q.Description,
        AnswerItems = q.AnswerItems.Select(a => new 
            { 
                Name = a.Defenition, 
                IsCorrect = a.IsCorrect
            })
            .ToList()
        }
    };

var result = query.ToList();
```

Comment: If this answered your question, please mark it as Answered.